# Tips for uneven door weatherstripping

Tags: doors, gap, weatherstripping

I have an exterior door that is uneven on the left side (right hand opening).
The current weatherstripping takes care of the top half (36" or so) but you can still see daylight on the bottom half. I believe the top half is about 1/2-inch gap, and the bottom half is up to 1" gap.
**To avoid replacing the door or door jambs**, my idea is to *nail or glue* some additional weatherstripping on the bottom half, but I am not sure how effective that would be.
Any tips?

Comment: Pictures will help, but with that big of a gap I would screw and glue a spacer/filler(wood) to the bottom of the door and then use weatherstripping.  If gap is uneven, measure well and cut to size to leave a 1/4 to 1/2 gap.

Comment: An excellent solution from This Old House here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZwObQt4xg the solution you may draw from this is exactly the same as @crip659's.