# Replace shoe or rebuild threshold?

Tags: insulation, doors, waterproofing, sill

So I decided to paint the front door and remove the old door shoe. (sweep) The plastic was warped and pulling away from the door.  I took the old shoe to all the big box stores, the local hardware store and the local lumber store.  No one has seen anything like it.  It is not just a U shaped shoe unfortunately.

The door is an exterior in-swing door and has a bumper threshold.  [Pemco](http://constructionbuildingcomponents.com/catalogs/catalog-pemko.pdf) does not make anything like it! The threshold has two vinyl "steps" on the inside.  The door is well above both steps without the shoe. The outer "step" on the sill is higher and the door shoe gasket can make contact.  The inner "step" is lower and the shoe is supposed to meet the outer "step" but be over the inner "step" The shoe has a sold plastic square piece that comes down on the inside part and then meets the inner and outer vinyl steps on the sill. So the bumper on the threshold meets the shoe on the bottom of the door.

I have hit 6+ stores and spent a couple of hours searching but can't find a replacement shoe.  Is there a better solution than totally rebuilding the threshold of the door?

[image: Measurements of the Shoe]
[image: Old Door Shoe]
[image: Door Sill]

Comment: The second comment(video) of this question, might have something useful for you.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/279519/tips-for-uneven-door-weatherstripping

Comment: That is a unique shoe. Is it possible that something more normal would suffice, eg: https://cookandboardman.com/pemko-210-door-bottom-shoe/

Comment: TY! I watched the "This Old House" episode and really liked the idea of the automatic weather stripping.  Perhaps that can be the part of the door that comes down and mates with the step.  Then I can add another seal in-front of it.  Clearly not a replacement of the current solution but doing something different.  The video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZwObQt4xg 

The normal shoe does not mate up with the step which is a pretty big miss.  But maybe combine a normal shoe and the automatic stripping and there is a solution?  Clearly this is crafting something new vs a quick fix.

Comment: Evenutaully found this door Shoe / Sweep.  Looks like it will work.  https://www.amazon.com/Door-Shoe-Rain-Willmar-Doors/dp/B08WWHNQK3

Comment: And it turns out that the Willmar shoe in the comment above does not fit ... Just a little off.  But I did identify that the doors are Loewen doors and they have a replacement shoe.  Should be here in a week ...